# Get Exchange user events/appointments

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, exchange-server

I have an iOS app and I need to be able to fetch all of the appointments from Exchange users. Can anyone point me in a good direction on this? It seems possible since iPhone and other apps/Outlook can do it but I don’t see it in the IMAP protocol so I need a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

IMAP won't help you with with Exchange activities, contacts, tasks.
Use EWS - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119(v=exchg.140).aspx